# Typescript typing for custom store function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a custom store function with a get and set function. The problem I am having is setting the correct type for the setting of the store. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
type StoredData = {
    obj: {
        a: number,
        b: number
    },
    str: string
}

function createData<DataType>(initialData: DataType, reducer: (data: DataType, type: string, payload: any) => DataType) {
    let data: DataType = initialData

    function get() {
        return data
    }

    function set(type: string, payload?: any) {
        data = reducer(data, type, payload)
    }

    return { get, set }
}

function reducer(data: StoredData, type: string, payload?: any) : StoredData {
    switch(type) {
        case 'obj:a':
            return {
                ...data,
                obj: {
                    ...data.obj,
                    a: payload
                }
            }
        default:
            return data
    }
}

const data = createData<StoredData>({
    obj: {
        a: 0,
        b: 0
    },
    str: 'Hello'
}, reducer)


data.set('obj:a', 'a')
```

The problem here is that I obviously don't want to be able to set `obj.a` to a `string` because it is of type `number`. Right now this is perfectly valid because I have `any` as the payload value. But I don't know how to type this correctly without `any` on the payload because the setting function could take in any number of values.

So how would you go about typing this so that if you put a type into the `set()` function of `createData()` that would result in an incorrect type for the stored data you would get an error? Also this will be used to create any number of stored data types and not just `StoredData` type specified here. If you need clarification please let me know in the comments.

Comment: To make it work, I needed to use discriminated unions in the reducer function so that TypeScript is happy. Then I needed to create types to represent the store keys and payload types. I also had to add generics to basically everything. Lots of changes made, but it works: https://tsplay.dev/WKpBpw